# Not ShowInTaskbar in Window CE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

As we all know, ShowInTaskbar feature is not available in Window CE project.

How could we do it ? Please kindly share me.

Comment: did you see this http://blog.opennetcf.com/2005/08/04/stylin/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the `WS_EX_NOANIMATION` extended style bit *in the constructor* of the Form.

Here's an example using the SDF's `Win32Window` class, though you could also directly P/Invoke [`GetWindowLong`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.GetWindowLong) and `SetWindowLong` to get the same effect.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Capture = true;
    Win32Window hwnd = Win32Window.GetCapture();
    Capture = false;
    hwnd.ExtendedStyle |= WS_EX.NOANIMATION;
}
```